# Working program with Allegro 5 no longer functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, allegro5

I'm trying to make a game with Allegro 5 in Visual Studio Express 2012, but the old template I saved doesn't appear to be functional anymore. VS complains a lot about two particular files, file.h and fmaths.h, griping about everything from syntax errors to undeclared identifiers. Here are my errors:

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '__cdecl'   c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\file.h  33  1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_FILE'   c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\file.h  33  1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   3   error C2091: function returns function  c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\file.h  33  1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\file.h  33  1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   6   error C2065: 'ERANGE' : undeclared identifier   c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\inline\fmaths.inl   43  1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   7   error C2065: 'ERANGE' : undeclared identifier   c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\inline\fmaths.inl   72  1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   8   error C2065: 'ERANGE' : undeclared identifier   c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\inline\fmaths.inl   95  1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   9   error C2065: 'ERANGE' : undeclared identifier   c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\inline\fmaths.inl   172 1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   10  error C2065: 'ERANGE' : undeclared identifier   c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\inline\fmaths.inl   194 1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   11  error C2065: 'EDOM' : undeclared identifier c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\inline\fmaths.inl   235 1   Super Boulder Whisperer
Error   12  error C2065: 'EDOM' : undeclared identifier c:\allegro5-msvc11\include\allegro5\inline\fmaths.inl   246 1   Super Boulder Whisperer
```

I'm not completely convinced that there is a problem with my includes and dependencies since this program at one time was building perfectly fine on the same machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Go to the Output window instead of the Error List and figure out which of your own files these are ultimately related to. Something may be broken before these includes. (The Error List is pretty rubbish for finding out what's gone wrong, since it doesn't show any context.)

Comment: Seems in the output window its main gripes are with file.h (complaining about a few different things) and fmaths.inl (complaining about undeclared identifiers). This is an allegro file, though, so I'm not entirely sure what the actual problem is.

Comment: Which Allegro version are you using? Looking at line 33 of file.h in the most recent Allegro 5 (5.2.2), I see no way that you could get those messages other than by redefining the `AL_METHOD` macro. But your line numbers in fmaths.inl don't match the code in 5.2.2... (In any case, you need to figure out what happens *before* `#include "file.h"`. Look for your own files in the output.)

Comment: I am using version 5.0.10. I would be using 5.2.2 if I could find some documentation on implementing it with Visual Studio 2012 (after acquiring it via NuGet), but due to time constraints I deferred to Ol' Reliable that has evidently become slightly less reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar problem after modifying my include directories. After checking the build output log to see which file was to blame, I noticed that it was complaining about a header file that wasn't even included by the file in question.

It turns out one of my header files had the same name as one of the header files included by Allegro, and the new path I added to my include directories was taking priority when locating the file. It was including my header file instead of the one Allegro was actually looking for.

If you have any header files with simple names like "File.h", "IO.h", etc. that are likely to be in use, try renaming them to something else.